# Blogger-Bottom Posts Repeat on Next Page (Not blog2 Prob)

Tags: xml, blogger

This is not a blog2 problem in the code. Confused and need help.

In blogger, if I configure my settings to show 4 posts for "Number of posts on main page", everything is fine. However, if I change it to 5 posts to show on the main page, this duplicates the last post on the second page. Duplication of posts can increase as I change the "Number of posts on main page".

How do I correct this to change the "Number of posts on main page" of my choice without having the problem above?

My blog is at http://praiseourking.blogspot.com

Thanks,
Glenn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your javascript code is Overriding blogger settings. In javascript code `max-result` is set to **4**, so when you change blogger settings to show 4 posts per page then everything is fine, but when it's something else your code Override it to make it 4.

For example
 you set 6 posts per page in blogger. on home page it will show 6 posts, but when you press **next page** button and script runs, it will assume that first page had 4 posts and it has to show next 4 posts, so the 2 posts form first page gets repeated.

**Solution**
make the number of posts in javascript equal to number of posts in blogger settings.
Blogger dashBoard > Template > Edit HTML 
 find first **script** at the bottom of body tag
cahnge `var posts = 4` to `var posts = 6` or any number you want, make sure it's same in both places(blogger settings and script)

Comment: Thank you very much. Been researching this for days.

Comment: Just tested it simr. Works great. Thank you. Your are awesome. Been researching and posting my issue among the web. You answered it and it worked. Glenn